# maven project run successfully but cann't build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have a `Maven` projects and i want to build a project with `Maven` to create excutable `JAR`

I can run the project successfully but
when i run `Maven build...` in `eclipse` with the command `clean package` i get(this is just a sample of the log but the rest of the log just repeat the same type of errors)

> [INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\StrockMarketAnalyzer\USB\master\integ\target\classes
>       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
>       [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
>       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
>       [ERROR] C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx-parent\xxx-  integ\src\main\java\com/xxx/xxx/xxx\communicationInterface\IbfAdministrator.java:[22,48] error: package com.xxx/xxx/xxx.businessObject does not exist
>       [ERROR] C:\xxx\xxx\xxx-parent\xxx-integ\src\main\java\com\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\communicationInterface\IbfAdministrator.java:[23,48] error: package com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.businessObject does not exist

and this is the `pom.xml` of the project i want to build.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>integ</artifactId>
```

I am using `packages` from `other projects` that i created when i look to the `JAR's` in Maven dependency i can find the other projects with a folder icone and Inside them i can find there dependency but not there packages.

I hope there're enough information for you to know what's the problem

Comment: The first thing to check is that `businessObject` exists in the parent project. If not, hen you need to pull a dependency.
Placing a dependency in the parents dependencyManagement section does not pull it in, you need to define it in either the parent, or child `dependencies` section.
Hope this helps

Comment: thank's for you comment @jr593 , i define `businessObject`  in the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the parent project (with the same conf.)not the project it self.

Answer (score 0):

Right klik project --> update project, wait for the Workbench to build then build using maven. This is a stopgap and not a permanent solution which i myself have not found yet.

Answer (score 0):

You probably "run" the previous version of a program, without building it new.
You must write the dependencies and (their) repositories you use in pom.xml, the parent tag is strange to me.
Also, if you have dependency to another project you r working on clean and build it first.